# What EXACTLY does the windows + D shortcut do?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop

Hello i am making a program that displays widgets above the desktop. I have to prevent my application minimizing when using the show desktop (Windows+D) shortcut. To prevent this i have to understand what exactly it does. How does it close all things? Does it's Z-Index change? etc..

Thank you

Comment: You asked the wrong question.  If somebody answers it then you'll know you can't trust the answer.